# How to get week number based on Two dates based Conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a DateTime column in Excel in which data is sorted in ascending order based on DateTime conditions from 15th June to say 1st November ;
I want to print Week Number from 1st to Nth Week based on date condition; Week criteria are like first seven days i.e 15th June to 21st June is Week1, 22nd Jun-28th Jun is Week2, 29th June - 5th June is Week3 and so on.

How Can I do this?

```
Column1

06/15/2021 8:00
06/15/2021 10:00
:
:

11/01/2021 20:44
11/01/2021 20:46
```

Comment: You have not shown us anything you have tried so far, nor given much information. Have you looked at the WEEKNUM() function? Combined with WEEKDAY() you will be a long way towards a solution.

Comment: @Richard, my approach  basically is that in the First weekly column I am providing the week no as 1, in say B2 Cell (in Column 2), and then I am applying this formula =(TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")
-TEXT(($A$2),"yyyy-mm-dd"))/7+1 and taking Round of the result and then dragging the formula in B3 to all other cells

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Excel or sheets? If excel, please do remove the sheets tag.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your list of dates is in A2:A.

Place the following formula in cell B2 of an otherwise empty range B2:B...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,ROUNDDOWN((INT(A2:A)-INT(A2))/7)+1))`

`INT` is just removing the times from date-times.

The rest is really more of a math/logic question than a formula question.